# Change backups folder outside magento root folder

Tags: magento2, backup

Im using magento and i want write script to automatically backup so i want store the outside the magento 2 root directory is it possible and how can i do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do outside Magento folder.

First create a **plugin** for `Magento\Backup\Helper\Data` of function `getBackupsDir()`. Then on **`afterGetBackupsDir`** changes the **dir** of backup.

### Define plugin in di.xml

Define plugin at a **`app/code/{Vendor}/{Modulename}/di.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Backup\Helper\Data">
        <plugin name="change_backup_dir" type="{VendorName}\{Modulename}\Plugin\DataBackupPlugin" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
</config>
```

### Plugin Class:

```
<?php
namespace {VendorName}\{Modulename}\Plugin;
class DataBackupPlugin
{
    public function afterGetBackupsDir(
        \Magento\Backup\Helper $subject,
        array  $result
    )
    {
        /* Should Use Absolulated path */
        /* Here  i have set my back directory is /var/www/ */
        return '/var/www/';

    }

}
```